# Error while creating SSRS report by creating an XML from VB Code

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, reporting-services

I am creating a report in SSRS from Visual Studio by creating an xml file in VB.

Getting below error while trying to display it.

```
An Error Occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report " is invalid.
The ColSpan of the tablix 'tablixReporttabledata' has an invalid value. The ColSpan must be 0, if the TablixCell has no CellContents; or greater than 0, if TableCell has CellContents.
```

I tried removing ColSpan from xml but after that I am getting below error:

```
An Error Occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report " is invalid.
The tablix "tablixReporttableData" has an incorrect number of Tablixcells. The number of TablixCells in a TablixRow must equal the number of innermost TablixMembers(TablixMembers with no submembers) in the TableColumnHierarchy.
```

I am new to SSRS. What steps do I need to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Could you post some of the code related to the section that formats the ColSpan area in your VB?

Comment: Are you trying to create an SSRS report by manually writing the xml code?  Or do you have an existing report that you're trying to call from VB code and export as XML?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to generate the RDL via code.  It can be done, but it is very fragile and has several tests for consistency, before it will render a report. The ReportViewer engine is unforgiving.  If you show the XML (RDL) that you generated, we can help point-out the inconsistency and problem/solution.